# Geometric meaning of Equation

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, quadratic-forms, bilinear-form

As a part of my linear-algebra exam preparation, I am going through the surface equation and quadratic-bilinear form usage in my book which is a part we haven't really went through and left to explore on our own. I've found myself hitting the wall on the following type of exercise :

Given the equation $2x^2 + 2y^2 + 2z^2 + 2xy + 2xz + 2yz - 1=0$ show that the surface described by it has a unique center of symmetry $\big( O(0,0)\big)$ and after performing a coordinate system change, describe the type of the surface that this equations defines.

Now, what I have thought initially is that the $q_D(x,y,z)=2x^2 + 2y^2 + 2z^2 + 2xy + 2xz + 2yz $ is a quadratic form, which we can fully investigate and write its matrix down. After that, the question we need to answer is what $q_D(x,y,z) = 1$ describes. But, it seems like I cannot understand where the change of the coordinate system is needed and I also do not know how to proceed with this specific type of a problem. I've seen though another type of problem which was handled the way I tried to approach this one (it was a quadratic form-like equation again), but that doesn't seem to be the case here. Any help, hint or thorough solution will be really appreciated !

Comment: Is this of any help? $(x+y)^2+(y+z)^2+(z+x)^2=1$

Comment: That could show the symmetry, but what about the coordinate change ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $v=(x,y,z)$ then

$$
v A v^{T} =1
$$

where $A=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 2\end{pmatrix}
$

you can check that $A$ has eigenvalues $1,1,4$ with eigenvectors

$$
v_1=(1,0,-1)^{T} \;\;\; v_2=(0,1,-1)^{T} \;\;\; v_3=(1,1,1)^{T}
$$

It's easy to see $v_1\cdot v_2\neq 0$ but any other pairs of vectors are orthogoanal, so apply Grams schmidt to these two to get an orthonormal basis $w_1,w_2,w_3$ where $w_3=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} v_3$. Set $P=[w_1,w_2,w_3]$, so

$$
P^{-1}AP=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 4\end{pmatrix}
$$

Now this is in canonnical form, and so surface is an ellipsoid